# Applying the output of a function to two columns using .apply

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a script that takes in an address and spits out two values: coordinates (as a list) and result (whether the geocoding was successful or not.  This works fine, but since the data is returned as a list, I then have to assign new columns based on the indices of that list, which works but returns a warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy.
```

EDIT: Just to be clear, I think I understand from that page that I should be using .loc to access the nested values.  My question is more along the lines of generating two columns directly from a function as opposed to this workaround of having to dig the information out later.

I'd like to know the correct way to approach problems like these, as I actually have this problem twice in this project.

The actual specifics of the problem aren't important, so here's a simple example of how I've been approaching it:

```
def geo(address):
    location = geocode(address)
    result = location.result
    coords = location.coords
    return coords, result

df['output'] = df['address'].apply(geo)
```

Since this then yields a nested list into my df column, I then extract that into new columns as such:

```
df['coordinates'] = None
df['gps_status'] = None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df['coordinates'][index] = df['output'][index][0]
    df['gps_status'][index] = df['output'][index][1]
```

And again, I get the warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Any advice on the correct way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you want to avoid iterrows() since it is faster to operate on an entire column at once. You can assign the result from output directly to a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

def geo(x):
    return x*2, x*3

df = pd.DataFrame({'address':[1,2,3]})

output = df['address'].apply(geo)

df['a'] = [x[0] for x in output]
df['b'] = [x[1] for x in output]
```

gives you

```
   address  a  b
0        1  2  3
1        2  4  6
2        3  6  9
```

with no copy warning.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return a Series:

```
def geo(address):
    location = geocode(address)
    result = location.result
    coords = location.coords
    return pd.Series([coords, result], ['coordinates', 'gps_status'])

df['output'] = df['address'].apply(geo)
```

---

That said, this may be better written as a [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

Comment: Thanks. Thought about doing a merge but this seemed liked fewer steps.

Comment: @MichaelPolansky was here an issue with this answer, using a list comprehension is not the pandas way...